# I am getting error when creating menus in joomla on server

Tags: joomla3.0

PHP Warning:  is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(\metadata.xml) is not within the allowed path(s): (D:/INETPUB/VHOSTS//canopussystems.com\;C:\Windows\Temp) in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\canopussystems.com\ecommerce.canopussystems.com\mycart\cart\administrator\components\com_menus\models\item.php on line 951

Comment: Hi! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can bypass this if you don't have access to server configeration -in my case I don't- by editing the php code in the administrator\components\com_menus\models\item.php

look up

```
        $option = '';
        $base = '';

        if (isset($args['option']))
        {
            // The option determines the base path to work with.
            $option = $args['option'];
            $base = JPATH_SITE . '/components/' . $option;
        }
```

and replace it with

```
        $option = '';
        $base ='';

        if (isset($args['option']))
        {
            // The option determines the base path to work with.
            $option = $args['option'];
            $base = 'D:/INETPUB/VHOSTS/canopussystems.com\ecommerce.canopussystems.com\mycart\cart'. '/components/' . $option;
        }
```

that worked for me till I get access to php configuration . u should make sure the path is correct though.

Answer (score 0):

Check php configuration using `<?php  phpinfo(); ?>` 
Search php.ini file and change settings .
And search "open_basedir" that file. then replace

```
open_basedir = "/var/www/htdocs/:/var/www/tmp/"
```

Comment: can you please explain me briefly how can I change the setting in php.ini file

Comment: localhost or other server ?

Comment: Parallel plesk 11.0 version windows based server

Comment: we are not getting php.ini file in our windows server plesk cpanel please tell me where I can find it

Comment: Go to cpanel > PHP Scripting